# Multiply numbers using SQL and if else statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do query. ı use Microsoft sql

if product is equal FAST and tree_level is equal 0,1,2,3,4,5 count the number 0,1,2,3,4,5 and multiply 2 and tree_level equal -1 count number multiply 2

and
if product is equal MOBIL and tree_level is equal 0,1,2,3,4,5 count the number multiply 3
and

if product is equal FACE and tree_level is equal 0,1,2,3,4,5 count the number 0,1,2,3,4,5 and multiply 3 and tree_level equal -1 count number multiply 2

I want to do it same query but I can not do algorithm

**Joıned table**

```
perstel| AD|SOYAD|RefPhoner|Product |Tree_level
_______________________________________________
7857887|AS |DFDSF|5645545  |FAST    |0
6566464|SD |DFDDS|4578857  |MOBİL   |1
7487887|SD |FSDFD|8787878  |FACE    |2 
7487887|SD |FSDFD|8788278  |FACE    |2 
7487887|SD |FPOFD|8933878  |MOBIL   |5 
7445887|WE |FSPLD|8771878  |FACE    |3 
7387887|SD |LBDFD|8712878  |FAST    |4 
0487887|WE |FSPLD|8771878  |FACE    |-1
4487887|WE |FOLLD|8771878  |MOBIL   |-1
```

**ı want this out put** ı update it for understable

```
perstel| AD(name at eng)|SOYAD|RefPhoner|Product |Tree_level | POint
_________________________________________________________________
7857887|AS       |DFDSF|5645545  |FAST    |-1         | 2 (because it is -1 and it is face so it is point 2)
6566464|EM       |DFDDS|4578857  |FACE    |2          | 3 (because it is 2 and it is face  so it is point 3)
7487887|MM       |FSDFD|8787878  |FAST    |2          | 2 .....
7487887|AS       |DFDSF|8788278  |MOBIL   |0          | 3 ...
7487887|EM       |DFDDS|8933878  |FAST    |-1         | 2 ...
7445887|HL       |FSPLD|8771878  |FACE    |3          | 3 ...
```

so ı will sum person'S ALL Of point  after that

ı only do that :(

```
select
    DS.PersTel ,
    DW.AD ,
    DW.SOYAD ,
    DS.RefPhoner   ,
    DS.Product ,
    DS.Tree_level 

    from dw_prod.FRTN.DIG_SEFER  AS DS 
    inner join dw_prod.dbo.DW_MUST AS DW 
    ON DW.CEP_TEL = DS.PersTel
```

**I UPDATE IT I TRYed it but it still have mistake what is my mistake**

```
   select
    DS.PersTel ,
        DW.AD ,
        DW.SOYAD ,
        DS.RefPhoner   ,
        DS.Product ,
        DS.Tree_level 
    CASE DS.Tree_level 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
    WHERE DS.Product like '%FACE%' END AS Answer1

    CASE DS.Tree_level 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
    WHERE DS.Product like '%MOBIL%' END AS Answer2

    CASE DS.Tree_level 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
    WHERE DS.Product like '%FAST%' END AS Answer3

    from dw_prod.FRTN.DIG_SEFER  AS DS 
        inner join dw_prod.dbo.DW_MUST AS DW 
        ON DW.CEP_TEL = DS.PersTel
```

**updated case part**

```
       select
        DS.PersTel ,
            DW.AD ,
            DW.SOYAD ,
            DS.RefPhoner   ,
            DS.Product ,
            DS.Tree_level 
    CASE  
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5)AND DS.Product LIKE '%FACE%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
    END AS Answer1 

    CASE DS.Tree_level
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) AND DS.Product LIKE '%MOBIL%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
    END AS Answer2 

    CASE  DS.Tree_level
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) AND DS.Product LIKE '%FAST%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
    END AS Answer3

  from dw_prod.FRTN.DIG_SEFER  AS DS 
            inner join dw_prod.dbo.DW_MUST AS DW 
            ON DW.CEP_TEL = DS.PersTel
```

Comment: You can't use a WHERE for a CASE statement, you need to use the other CASE syntax e.g. `CASE WHEN X AND Y THEN 0` rather than `CASE X WHEN Y THEN 0`. Applied to your first `CASE` it would be `CASE  WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) AND DS.Product LIKE '%FACE%' THEN ....`

Comment: yes ı update it but it still give error on case :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query and do let me know if u still facing problem

```
select
DS.PersTel ,
DW.AD ,
DW.SOYAD ,        
DS.RefPhoner   ,
DS.Product ,
DS.Tree_level ,
CASE  
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) And DS.Product LIKE '%FACE%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) And DS.Product LIKE '%FAST%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) AND DS.Product LIKE '%FACE%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) AND DS.Product LIKE '%MOBIL%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) AND DS.Product LIKE '%FAST%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2 
    Else DS.Tree_level 
END AS Answer1 
from dw_prod.FRTN.DIG_SEFER  AS DS 
inner join dw_prod.dbo.DW_MUST AS DW 
ON DW.CEP_TEL = DS.PersTel
    Group by DS.PersTel , DW.AD , DW.SOYAD , DS.RefPhoner   , DS.Product , DS.Tree_level
```

Comment: YES but ı want to separate case  WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2 for fast and face

Comment: so do u want 3 seprate columns ??

Comment: no but it can be changed at future you said if tree_level is -1 , multiply 2 ...but ı add more information if tree_level is -1 and if it is fast multiply 2.. and if tree_level is -1 and if it is face multiply 2.. but at face case number of 2 can be changed for example it can be 3,4.. so ı have to separate two statue

Comment: @ADKu can u please check it now ?? and pls accept answer if it will work for u

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:

```
CASE DS.Tree_level 
WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
WHERE DS.Product like '%FACE%' END AS Answer1
```

But you can do:

```
CASE 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) AND DS.Product like '%FACE%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
    WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) AND DS.Product like '%FACE%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
END AS Answer1
```

(or you could nest case statements but that might be uglier!)

Update:

Just make sure you separate each 'case' with a comma:

```
CASE  
WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5)AND DS.Product LIKE '%FACE%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (-1) THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 2
END AS Answer1, -- COMMA HERE IMPORTANT 

CASE DS.Tree_level
WHEN DS.Tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) AND DS.Product LIKE '%MOBIL%' THEN count(DS.Tree_level) * 3 
END AS Answer2
```

Because you need to separate the fields as you would with a normal query:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM X
```

or

```
SELECT CASE X WHEN Y THEN Z END as Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM X
```

The comma is important (you don't need a comma before the FROM, just between each field)

Comment: yes update it but it still gives error case statement. ı can not use join and case statement together

Comment: You can - just remember to add a comma at the end of each case - after the `AS Answer1` - I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CASE statement in SQL Server.

Example from MSDN

```
Simple CASE expression: 
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END 
Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

[Link Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Something like

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN tree_level IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN tree_level * 2 END AS Answer1
....
```

Comment: but it is joined table how can ı do with this join?

Comment: it doesn't matter if it's a joined table.